# Input database table to another table codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I've been working on my college final project (for Web Programming) using Codeigniter.

Somehow, I have a crazy idea, I have that crazy plan on my mind but I'm really stuck with that now..

So here's the idea
I have a html page "admins/pengurus"

In my html I have 2 table.

1. tbl_members
2. tbl_registration

Is it possible to transfer data inside DB tbl_registration, into DB tbl_members?

I want to add/input data that has been set as a tabel on my html.

So when a new members click "done" on registration, the data will be filled on tbl_registration and then appear on admins/pengurus page.

I want to input the data on this tbl_registration, into tbl_members by clicking an input button written as "CONFIRM"

So it's like the waiting list. Admin will have to CONFIRM this new data registration. After it confirmed, the data will be sent to tbl_members.

Sorry for long post. And grammar. But, is it really possible? I think these are crazy enough..

Comment: So basically you want to copy data from `tbl_registration` to `tbl_members.` when admin confirms the user

Comment: Isn't easier to have only one table with field like 'is_registered', 'active' etc? Or status = 'pending', 'active', 'banned'

Comment: and how to upload photo here.. Totally newbie here :o

Answer (score -1):

You can just read the data from the first table (lets say tbl_registration) and insert it to the new table (tbl_members).

And then if you want yo can delete the row in the first table, or just leave it here and add a column named "confirmed" if you want to hide it from the results.